# Encoding to WebM and OggVorbis without changing original dimensions?

Tags: video, ogg, theora, webm

Trying to convert original Quicktime.movs to both WEbM and OggVorbis-Theora formats.

Was using the free Miro video converter but when it converts it always uses preset sizes.

Is there any way of keeping a video's original dimensions?

Comment: Must it be with Miro?

Comment: Actually after some research am using Quicktime. Not sure why Miro is even recommended.

Comment: What OS are you using, even?

Comment: OSX- unfortunately upgraded to lion:)